# jQuery: items/classes with same names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I downloaded 2 plugins http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/itemsperpage.html  and  http://jplayer.org/.
The 2 plugins are both using `jp-next` and `jp-previous` names.
Is there anyway i can make this work ?
Maybe i can somehow limit the `.js` file of one plugin inside a `<div>` and the other `.js` file in another `<div>`?
Or can i possibly rename the `jp-next` and `jp-previous` to something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing jp-next or jp-previous as css selectors in the jPlayer documentation http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-predefined-css-selectors however I do see those listed as part of jPages https://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/. In the case of jPlayer, you can override the default css selectors so if you run into some sort of conflict they can be renamed as docs in the link above show in the constructor.

Comment: css selector  in the jPlayer cant be edited for jp-next or jp-previous, i gave it a try

Comment: where exactly are jp-next and jp-previous being used? I do not see them even listed in the documentation for jPlayer.

Comment: they are used in the `next` `previous` song in the playlist in the `bm ( blue monday ) ` theme http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-video/?theme=0

Comment: well that makes sense as to why they aren't showing on the basic jPlayer, it's an add-on. i'll take a look

Comment: so it seems you should be able to add the next and previous as override options the same way you can edit other selectors in the cssSelector object that i linked to. if not and the plugin ends up overriding them, which i think it might, here's the line it is setting it with and you could modify that https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/add-on/jplayer.playlist.js#L61